# Overriding the FILE_LOG_PATTERN (if possible per env)

Tags: spring-boot, logback

I want to override Spring Boot's default file and console log pattern to include some custom MDC fields.

Is there an easy way to change this using `application.properties/yaml`? If not this would be a nice feature :-)

Otherwise I probably have to copy Boot's `/src/main/resources/org/springframework/boot/logging/logback base.xml` and `basic.xml` files.

I don't think logback supports including those files and overriding property values, or does it?

Comment: As far as I can tell your assessment of Logback's support for overriding properties is correct. For this to be possible some changes in Spring Boot will be required, I think. Please feel free to open an issue (https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues)

Comment: OK, just created https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/1788

Comment: I think I have a related problem. I want to add MDC context and if I can't override spring boot's CONSOLE_LOG_PATTERN with my MDC value added, then it seems I have to live with every log message being written twice! (once with the spring boot console appender and once with my console appender with MDC added to the pattern)

Comment: @pastafarian you can override it but not yet via application properties. You can provide a custom log back or log4j xml as described in Boot's ref guide.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently not possible (Boot 1.2.2). See also feature request: 
https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/1788

Answer (score 0):

Just come to the same issue a few year after this question, in the latest the springboot, we could overwrite it by adding a property before including the default base.xml into the XML config file logback-spring.xml

```
<property name="CONSOLE_LOG_PATTERN" value="%clr(%d{${LOG_DATEFORMAT_PATTERN:-yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS}}){faint} %clr(${LOG_LEVEL_PATTERN:-%5p}) %clr([%X{USER_ID}|%X{URL}]){magenta} %clr(---){faint} %clr([%15.15t]){faint} %clr(%-40.40logger{39}){cyan} %clr(:){faint} %m%n${LOG_EXCEPTION_CONVERSION_WORD:-%wEx}"/>

<include resource="org/springframework/boot/logging/logback/base.xml"/>
```