# Is it possible to modify log appender parameters via application.properties in Spring Boot?

Tags: java, logging, log4j, spring-boot

In Spring Boot, I can select/enable logger levels via the application.properties file:

```
logging.level.org.springframework=DEBUG
logging.level.org.hibernate=ERROR
```

But is there some way to modify the actual appender thresholds/parameters via the same config file?  I know I can do it via my log4j.xml file directly, but was hoping to have some way I can easily do it via a command line parameter.

I've tried stuff like (where I have an appender called console)

```
logging.appender.console.param.Threshold=DEBUG
```

but with no success.

As anything like that doable?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26629197/overriding-the-file-log-pattern-if-possible-per-env

Comment: @Avis - I had seen that question already.  That one relates specifically to Logback, and the Github issue also relates more to logback configuration.  This question is a) more general in nature (not specific to logback), but if I had to target an implementation, it would be log4j.  b) I'm looking to modify appender parameters.  c) I'm looking to do it via the spring config logging properties in my application.properties file.

Answer (score 1):

If you're happy to use Logback (Spring Boot's default and preferred logging system), you can do it via command line parameters as long as you provide a suitably configured `logback-spring.xml` file first.

You can reference properties from the environment (provided on the command line, in application.properties, etc), in your `logback-spring.xml` file. For example:

```
<springProperty scope="context" name="consoleThreshold" source="logging.appender.console.param.Threshold"/>
```

You can then use that property elsewhere in the same file using `${consoleThreshold}`.

These capabilities are specific to Logback. There's an [open issue](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/4032) that may expand the support to other logging systems. That said, it's highly unlikely that Log4J will be included – it's been declared EOL by Apache and support for it is deprecated in Spring Boot 1.3. Log4J 2 is more likely.

Comment: Oh wow; thanks for the heads up.  I hadn't realized that Log4j has become EOL'ed.  Any ideas why Spring chose Logback as the preferred logger over Log4j2?

Comment: Log4J2 wasn't an option when Spring Boot was first being developed; Spring Boot 1.0 was released in April 2014 but Log4J2 didn't GA until July.

Comment: Ah thanks for the history lesson.  I suspected it was something like that, but wasn't sure.  Any talk that Spring Boot will embrace Log4J2 as the preferred system?

Comment: No, I don't think so. Certainly not in the 1.x line anyway.